# Excepción al tratar de asignar valores a una Activity que aun no se ha ingresado

Tags: java, android-studio, json, android-asynctask

espero entiendan la pregunta aquí lo explico mas a detalle, resulta que tengo un carrito de compras este carrito de compras esta presente en 3 actividades la primera es donde obtengo los productos según su categoría la segunda en en las categorías y la tercera en obtener todos los productos, el punto es que tengo una consulta para que cada vez que agrego un producto el contador se vaya incrementando pero recibo una excepción cuando entro a todos los productos de primero y a la otra no ósea a la actividad donde obtengo los productos según su categoría, esto pasa porque cuando entro a una actividad y a la otra no le asigno el contador a un TextView de una actividad que aun no se ha creado ósea tengo que pasar por todas las actividades donde le asigno un valor al TextView antes de inicia el contador.
Tratare de explicar a detalle el código:

Como primer lugar tengo mi clase contadorProductos esta nada mas es un Asyntask y funciona para poder hacer la petición al WebService con httpResponse

```
public class ContadorProductos {

public static class GetDataFromServerIntoTextView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public Context context;
    HttpResponse httpResponse;
    JSONArray jsonObject = null;
    String StringHolder = "" ;
    String contador_url = "http://pedidoslab.6te.net/consultas/contadorProdPedidos.php" + "?id_prefactura=" + Login.gIdPedido;

    public static Double gCount = 0.0;
   DecimalFormat formatoDecimal = new DecimalFormat("#");

    public GetDataFromServerIntoTextView(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
    {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(contador_url);

        try {
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            StringHolder = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(StringHolder);
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONArray(0);

        } catch ( Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        try {

            JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(StringHolder));
            gCount = (responseJSON.getJSONArray("voto").getJSONObject(0).getDouble("count"));

    //Justo en esta parte es donde seteo el contador a cada textview que se encuentra en las 3 
    //diferentes acividades
            
     ObtenerProductos.tvCantProductos.setText(String.valueOf(formatoDecimal.format(gCount)));
                
     ObtenerCategorias.tvCantProd3.setText(String.valueOf(formatoDecimal.format(gCount)));
                
     ObtenerAllProductos.tvCantProductos2.setText(String.valueOf(formatoDecimal.format(gCount)));

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Luego en el adaptador de cada actividad mando a llamar este método cada vez que el usuario agregue un producto

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductosViewHolder productosViewHolder, int i) {

productosViewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(v -> {

new ContadorProductos.GetDataFromServerIntoTextView(productosViewHolder.itemView.getContext())
    .execute();

}
}
```

Clase completa del adaptador

```
public class AdaptadorProductos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorProductos.ProductosViewHolder> {

Context context;
public static List<Productos> listaProductos;
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static TextView tvCantProductos;
public static List<Productos> carroCompra;

public AdaptadorProductos(Context context, List<Productos> listaUsuarios, TextView tvCantProductos, List<Productos> carroCompra) {
    this.context = context;
    listaProductos = listaUsuarios;
    AdaptadorProductos.tvCantProductos = tvCantProductos;
    AdaptadorProductos.carroCompra = carroCompra;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public ProductosViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_rv_productos, viewGroup, false);
    return new ProductosViewHolder(v);
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductosViewHolder productosViewHolder, int i) {


    //final Productos user = listaProductos.get(i);

    //TODO: Obtiene el nombre y el precio del modelado (Getter y Setter) En este caso solo usamos el getter.
    productosViewHolder.tvNombre.setText(listaProductos.get(i).getNombreProducto());
    productosViewHolder.tvPrecio.setText(Double.toString(listaProductos.get(i).getPrecioProducto()));

    //TODO: Se le asigna un color al cardview cuando posteriormente sea seleccionado
    //productosViewHolder.view.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(user.isSelect() ? Color.GRAY : Color.rgb(0, 151, 167)));

    productosViewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        //TODO: Si el boton es seleccionado que cambie de color
        //user.setSelect(!user.isSelect());
        //productosViewHolder.view.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(user.isSelect() ? Color.GRAY : Color.rgb(0,151,167)));

        //TODO: Guardar el estado del carrito

        //TODO: Cantidad de productos que se actualizan graficamente en el carrito

        /*if (user.isSelect){
            tvCantProductos.setText(""+(Integer.parseInt(tvCantProductos.getText().toString().trim()) - 1));
            carroCompra.add(listaProductos.get(i));
        }*/

        //TODO: Obtiene elos productos para posteriormente mostrarlos en cada cardView (En este caso solo muestra el nombre y el precio.
        ObtenerProductos.gNombreProd = listaProductos.get(i).getNombreProducto();
        ObtenerProductos.gIdProducto = listaProductos.get(i).getIdProducto();
        ObtenerProductos.gPrecio = listaProductos.get(i).getPrecioProducto();
        ObtenerProductos.gDetMonto = ObtenerProductos.gPrecio / 1.13;
        ObtenerProductos.gDetMontoIva = ObtenerProductos.gDetMonto * 0.13;

        ObtenerProductos.gOpciones = listaProductos.get(i).getOpciones();

        /*if(ObtenerProductos.gOpciones == 1){
            Intent intent = new Intent(productosViewHolder.itemView.getContext(), ObtenerOpciones.class);
            productosViewHolder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }*/

        if (ObtenerProductos.gPrecio == 0.0){
            productosViewHolder.itemView.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if(Login.gIdPedido == 0) {
            new InsertarPedido(productosViewHolder.itemView.getContext()).execute();

        }

        try {
            new InsertarDetPedido(productosViewHolder.itemView.getContext()).execute().get();
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            if (InsertarDetPedido.exitoInsertProd) {
                AgregarProducto(v);
                new ContadorProductos.GetDataFromServerIntoTextView(productosViewHolder.itemView.getContext()).execute();
                new ContadorDetPedidos(productosViewHolder.itemView.getContext()).execute();

             }

         });
    }

public void AgregarProducto (View view){

    Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(view, "Producto agregado correctamente!",1000);
    view = snack.getView();
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params =(FrameLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    params.height = 120;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
    snack.setBackgroundTint(Color.rgb(52,140,55));
    snack.show();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        return listaProductos == null ? 0 : listaProductos.size();
}

public static class ProductosViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tvNombre, tvPrecio;
    public View view;

    public ProductosViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        view = itemView;

        tvNombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNombre);
        tvPrecio = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrecio);
    }
}

public void filtrar(ArrayList<Productos> filtroUsuarios) {
    listaProductos = filtroUsuarios;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Por ultimo cuando entro a una actividad a agregar productos pero aun no he entrado a la otra ma lanza la siguiente excepción.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Y la linea donde tengo la excepción es justo el TexView de la actividad a la que aun no he ingresado
y pues eso seria todo espero que se haya entendido lo que trato de solucionar si necesitan mas código porfavor decir y si la pregunta esta mal redactada porfavor editarla, de antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: No ha quedado muy claro. Si estás en una Activity (1) y quieres pasar a otra Activity (2) y mostrar en ella datos que tenías en (1) tienes que usar Intent para llamar a (2) desde (1) y al mismo tiempo pasarle los datos que quieres mostrar en (2). Sería interesante saber ¿por qué usas dos Activity en vez de una? O, ¿por qué no usas algo como LiveData para actualizar la UI si necesidad de cambiar de Activity (esto es algo más complejo, pero los tiros hoy día van por ahí si quieres implementar una arquitectura limpia)?

Comment: Esta clase ContadorProductos se encuentra dentro de la clase de tu Activity?, deberías agregar donde se define y se obtiene la referencia  del TextView.

Comment: Hola, gracias Cedano por responder, Si conforme a la primera respuesta te agradecería si me facilitas un ejemplo simple de como lo aplicaría a mi código busque información al respecto pero no comprendo muy bien LiveData por el momento.

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys si de hecho trate de ejecutar la consulta donde defino la referencia al TextView sin embargo la referencia nula siempre se detecta, lo que sucede es que cuando ingreso por ejemplo a la primera actividad donde obtengo los productos esta si se crea pero la segunda actividad donde obtengo los productos no se crea por lo tanto al momento de asignarle el contador al TextView de la actividad que aun no se ha creado me lanza la excepción...

Comment: @AdielMoran, para que los usuarios sean notificados utiliza el @ seguido del nombre.

Comment: @Christian Gracias!

Comment: Puedes poner la clase completa del adaptador?

Comment: Hola @LuisMiguelCasas ya he agregado la clase completa del adaptador

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu aplicación tiene serios problemas de arquitectura y, como consecuencia, la única forma que encontraste para que "funcione", es abusar de las propiedades estáticas para almacenar referencias a las views, lo cual conlleva los problemas de los que android studio intentó advertirte y que ignoraste con la anotación `@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")`. No hagas eso, si te muestra una advertencia es por una buena razón.
No voy a responder cómo cambiar el valor de un textView desde otra clase porque es algo que no debes hacer; en cambio, voy a darte una mejor alternativa.

En una arquitectura limpia y moderna, tu código debería estar separado en capas y la capa de UI debería actualizarse a sí misma observando los cambios que ocurren en la siguiente capa, es decir, en el viewModel. Esto se puede hacer, por ejemplo, con LiveData.
[image: arquitectura]
Además, la práctica de crear una activity por cada pantalla fue abandonada hace unos años. En la presentación [Single activity: Why, when, and how](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2k8x8V77CrU) del Android Dev Summit 2018, se introdujo el concepto de *destination* junto con el [navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) como forma recomendada de gestionar la UI. Lo que deberías hacer es tener una única activity cuya función sea simplemente contener todas las destinations que es donde deben estar las vistas. De esta manera puedes compartir información entre ellas usando un viewModel que viva en el scope de la activity.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Destination es sólo un concepto, su implementación real es la clase `Fragment`. Hay una implementación más nueva pero lo explicaré con fragments porque, como estás atrasado en varios aspectos, de otra manera sería un salto demasiado grande para ti.

Puedes empezar creando el viewModel cuya instancia será compartida entre todos los fragments. Por simplicidad pondré aquí la llamada al servidor pero en realidad debería ir en las próximas capas. Nótese que no hay ninguna referencia a views, todo lo que hace es actualizar el liveData.

```
public class ProductViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<Double> cantProductos = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private final Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

    public LiveData<Double> getCantProductos() {
        return cantProductos;
    }

    private Double getDataFromServer() {
        ...
    }

    public void loadData() {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Double gCount = getDataFromServer();
                cantProductos.postValue(gCount);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Luego sigue estos pasos para convertir tus activities en fragments:

- Has que hereden de la clase `Fragment`.
- Elimina el método `onCreate` y mueve todo su código (excepto el `setContentView`) al `onViewCreated`.
- Crea un constructor que pase su layout al contructor de su clase padre. Esto reemplaza el `setContentView(layout)`.
- Elimina su entrada del manifest.

Ejemplo:

```
public class ObtenerProductos extends Fragment {

    private ProductViewModel viewModel;

    public ObtenerProductos() {
        // infla la vista
        super(R.layout.example);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        TextView tvCantProductos = view.findViewById(R.id.tvCantProductos);
        // obtiene una instancia del view model asociada a la activity
        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ProductViewModel.class);
        // observa el liveData y ejecuta el callback cada vez que su valor cambia
        viewModel.getCantProductos().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), cantidad -> {
            tvCantProductos.setText(cantidad.toString());
        });
    }
}
```

Finalmente reemplaza los `startActivity(intent)` por transacciones de fragments. Esto puedes hacerlo con el [navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) o [manualmente](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager) (no recomendado). Para más información sobre cómo actualizar tu app, lee la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/first) y la [guía de arquitectura](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide).

Comment: Excelente, me ha funcionado muy bien!!!

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> cuando entro a una actividad a agregar productos pero aun no he
> entrado a la otra ma lanza la siguiente excepción.

Tratas de obtener las referencias de los `TexView` pero estos no se encuentra en la misma `Activity`

```
//Justo en esta parte es donde seteo el contador a cada textview que se encuentra en las 3 
//diferentes acividades
 ObtenerProductos.tvCantProductos.setText(String.valueOf(formatoDecimal.format(gCount)));                
 ObtenerCategorias.tvCantProd3.setText(String.valueOf(formatoDecimal.format(gCount)));                
 ObtenerAllProductos.tvCantProductos2.setText(String.valueOf(formatoDecimal.format(gCount)));
```

Las vistas de las cuales debes obtener la referencia deben encontrarse en el .xml que cargas en tu `Activity` mediante el mètodo `setContentView( )` :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstances){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

**No puedes acceder a la referencia de una vista si esta no se encuentra en el archivo .xml que se carga en tu `Activity` mediante  `setContentView()`**, por esta razòn es por la que obtienes el error :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
> object reference

Debes asegurar que los 3 `TextView` se encuentran en las 3 Actividades, pero debes obtener su referencia dentro de `onCreate()`

Comment: Hola te agradezco mucho por responder, fíjate que ya puse el código de las 3 referencias en los 3 activitys pero me sigue dando la misma excepción solo que ahora ya no en la clase contador si no en una de las referencias que acabo de agregar por ejemplo cuando entro a las categorías me dice que hay un objeto nulo en los productos, por lo visto entramos a la misma situación

Comment: Son Actividades las clases ObtenerProductos, ObtenerCategorias y ObtenerAllProductos? @AdielMoran

Comment: Hola si efectivamente son actividades.