# ¿Es posible cambiar el tiempo que tarda en ejecutarse un intent en android?

Tags: android-studio

Resulta que estoy creando una aplicacion, pero he notado que al ejecutar un intent a  cualquier nueva actividad tarda mas de 4 segundos, inlcuso si la nueva a actividad es una pantalla en blanco, he buscado pero no encuento si hay forma de acelerar el tiempo que tarde en ir a la nueva actividad.

Mi intent:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
```

Comment: no creo que se pueda, imagina que lo aceleras a 1s ¿Qué pasa si la activity  no esta cargada?

Comment: cargada? el metodo oncreate es que se ejecuta al pasar a la nueva actividad, entonces es ese metodo el qe se encarga de crear la vista y los procesos que se ha programado

Comment: lo siento creo que debí ser mas especifico, solo quería dar un concepto mas general

Comment: El sistema operativo es quién procesa los intents, no hay nada que puedas hacer. Pero esa tampoco es la forma recomendada de navegar.. Revisa [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/456220/198326) respuesta