# ¿Cómo llamar un ArrayList desde otro Activity?

Tags: java, android-studio, arraylist, android-listview

Estoy intentando hacer que al seleccionar un item de un ListView en la clase `Lista` llame a otro activity `Edit_DataBase` que me muestre información detallada del elemento seleccionado en el ListView. Los datos que se muestran en el ListView están almacenados en un ArrayList llamado `ListaUsuCar`. El problema surge cuando intento llamar al ArrayList `listaUsuCar` desde la clase `Edit_DataBase`, ya que no obtiene los valores del ArrayList o manda algún error. He intentado llamar el ArrayList `listaUsuCar` con

`intent.putStringArrayListExtra("ListaCarros", listaUsuCar);`

pero dice que los tipos son incompatibles, ya que espera un `ArrayList<String>` y no un `ArrayList<Carros>`

Tambien intenté llamar la lista desde la clase `Edit_DataBase` con el método `getter` del ArrayList `listaUsuCar` que construí en la clase `Lista`, pero tampoco ha funcionado. Espero puedan Ayudarme, es para un proyecto.

```
public class Lista extends AppCompatActivity {
    public ListView listViewCarros;
    private ArrayList<String> listaInfoCar;
    private ArrayList<Carros> listaUsuCar;
    BD_Helper conn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);

        conn = new BD_Helper(Lista.this);
        listViewCarros = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewCarros);

        consultarListaCarros();
        ArrayAdapter adaptador = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listaInfoCar);
        listViewCarros.setAdapter(adaptador);

        listViewCarros.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {

                //comprobar(listaUsuCar,pos);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Lista.this,Edit_DataBase.class);
                intent.putExtra("posi",pos);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("ListaCarros", listaUsuCar);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }


//En este método lleno el ArrayList listaUsuCar
    public void consultarListaCarros() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();

        Carros carro = null;
        listaUsuCar = new ArrayList<Carros>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_CARROS, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            carro = new Carros();
            carro.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            carro.setModelo(cursor.getString(1));
            carro.setMarca(cursor.getString(2));
            carro.setAño(cursor.getString(3));
            carro.setColor(cursor.getString(4));
            carro.setPrecio(cursor.getInt(5));
            carro.setConsumo(cursor.getString(6));
            carro.setImagen(cursor.getBlob(7));   //aqui tambien puede que sea blob
            listaUsuCar.add(carro);
        }
        obtenerLista();
    }

//Este es el método getter del ArrayList
 public ArrayList getListaUsuCar() {
        return listaUsuCar;
    }
```

Esta es la Clase Edit_DataBase

```
public class Edit_DataBase extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txtmarca;
    int posi;
    private Lista lista = new Lista();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit__data_base);

        txtmarca = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMarca);
        ArrayList<Carros> arrayCarros = lista.getListaUsuCar();

        /*listita = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("ListaCarros");
        posi = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("posi"));*/
        //txtmarca.setText(listita.get(posi).getMarca());
        posi = getIntent().getIntExtra("posi",0);
        System.out.println("El valor del pos en el Edit_DataBase es de: "+posi);

        //lista.listaUsuCar.get(lista.pos).getMarca()

    }
```

Comment: te sirve [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/456220/198326) respuesta?

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem La verdad soy inexperta programando en android Studio, y todo mi código está basado en tutoriales de youtube y foros que he encontrado con fecha de 2016 o anteriores. No tenía idea de que se podía crear un destination (fragment) para gestionar toda mi UI desde allí. Te agradezco por la sugerencia de usar una arquitectura más moderna para mi código pero carezco de conocimientos sobre cómo implementar estos nuevos métodos y sobre todo me falta tiempo para poder aprenderlo y así poder ponerlo en práctica en mi código.

Comment: Este proyecto está próximo a entregarse ya, y cambiar todo mi código en este momento me resulta muy tedioso.

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem Agradecería mucho una respuesta que se adapte a mi código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En principio sólo hay una forma de enviar datos a otra activity y es através de los extras del intent. Pero no puedes enviar cualquier tipo de dato, solamente primitivos, strings y parcelables/serializables.

Para enviar el carro seleccionado a la otra activity  tienes 3 opciones:

- Hacer que tu clase `Carros` implemente la interfaz `Parcelable` y enviarla en un único extra.
- Enviar un extra por cada propiedad del objeto seleccionado.
- Enviar el id del carro y usarlo en la nueva activity para hacer nueva consulta a la base de datos que traiga sólo los datos de ese carro.

Pero viendo que quieres tocar el menor código posible, voy a nombrar una más.

- No enviar nada y acceder directamente a la lista de la activity anterior.

De hecho esto es lo que intentaste hacer pero no funcionó porque creaste una nueva instancia. Este código `private Lista lista = new Lista()` crea una nueva activity que no es la misma que estabas viendo y , por lo tanto, sus propiedades son nulas.

Lo que necesitas hacer es marcar esas propiedades como `static`

```
public static ArrayList<Carros> listaUsuCar;
```

y luego podrás usarla desde otra activity así

```
ArrayList<Carros> arrayCarros = List.listaUsuCar;
```

Si quieres puedes hacerla privada y agregar un getter estático pero eso no la va a hacer menos mala.

**Por favor no usar esta opción en aplicaciones reales!**

Comment: Hola @Sinner of the System, siempre me resulta interesante leer tus respuestas. Me llama la atención tu comentario final de "no usar ésta opción en aplicaciones reales!", podrías explicar el motivo ? muchas gracias

Comment: Muchas gracias @SinneroftheSystem, me ha funcionado bien, aunque sé que esta no es una buena práctica. ¿Podrías recomendarme algún curso de Android Studio Online donde pueda aprender con implementaciones de código más modernas?

Comment: Lo mejor es hacer el [curso oficial](https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-kotlin/course) porque siempre va a estar actualizado. @el.trasgu en el sitio en inglés hay buenas respuestas sobre eso. Algunos ejemplos: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058835/static-fields-in-android) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908039/android-static-fields-and-memory-leaks). Es la peor forma pero lamentablemente es la más usada por novatos por ser la más simple.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @SinneroftheSystem, yo ahora estoy cursando el ciclo de DAM. Miraré los enlaces, graciass